# Why does Javascript filter focus lost

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a filter search for my search box, everything works well the array get filtered as i need, but it has a strange behaviour, since the search is almost at the bottom of the page (the scrool is at the bottom too) when i enter a character to search on the searchbox the scrool go up i think th ebehaviour has nothing to do with css, the problem is with my filter function.

**I do it this way:**

```
public onSearchChange(nameSearch: string): void {
    if (this.myFullArr) {
        const search = nameSearch.toLowerCase();
        this.myArr = this.myFullArr.filter((element) => {
            if (element.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })
    }
}
```

this function is called when my search box change, as you guys can see the myFullArr is the initial contend that is static and doesn't change, since i can't use just the original array because it will change, the myArr is the filtered array.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your `onSearchChange` function as follows.

```
    <input id="text" type="text" />

    the function

    document.getElementById('text').onkeydown = new function(event){
    onSearchChange("your search text")
    return false
}
```

You can get an idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997350/disable-scrolling-on-input-focus-in-javascript) question as well.